# Cloudflare http to https redirect for Lighttpd

Tags: https, lighttpd, cloudflare

I use cloudflare for my sites and need make default redirect from http to https. I use lighttpd web server without ssl, I wish use ssl of cloudflare.

I found article about [redirect http to https](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-) but I don't now, how make it for Lighttpd

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your lighttpd.conf file, assuming you have added the .pem and .crt files for your domain name. This uses mod_rewrite so under your server.modules don't forget to add mod_rewrite. Your lighttpd.conf file should look like this at the server.modules section

```
server.modules = (
"mod_access",
"mod_alias",
"mod_compress",
"mod_redirect",
"mod_simple_vhost",
"mod_setenv",
    "mod_rewrite",
)
```

At the end of lighttpd.conf file, append this so this will rewrite all HTTP links to HTTPS

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
$HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
    url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can force Cloudflare SSL by going to your Cloudflare domain settings.
Log in to your Cloudflare account. Under your desired domain, go to Crypto, and change SSL setting to Full. This should force all connections to be SSL.